# Why did Lilith help the factory if she wanted Manson destroyed?

Tags: comics, rachel-rising, terry-moore

In *Rachel Rising* #38 the readers learn that Lilith once met a banker she had known some 60 years before that, and her acquantance with said banker helped save the factory she worked at.

But why would she do that? Firstly, she hates Manson and wants to see it destroyed for good. Secondly, she seems to hate humanity in general, so helping anyone doesn't look like the sort of thing she'd do. And yet, she quite intentionally saved the factory from being closed, in a town she hates most.

Why?